# SPARQL filter by date range

Tags: sparql

I have a working SPARQL query which returns house price transactions for each day using the VALUES keyword. My goal is to amend this to allow queries which use a date range.

To do so, I have attempted to implement a FILTER in place of the VALUES keyword. This returns a 503 HTTP Error (Query timed out), whether I take a large range of dates, or filter down to a single date (which returned in << 1s with the original query).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

`endpoint: "http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/landregistry/query"`

**Original code**

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category

WHERE
{
  VALUES ?date {
  "2019-08-18"^^xsd:date
  }

  ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode.

  ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
          lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
          lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
          lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.

  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}
}

ORDER BY ?amount
```

**Proposed change**

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category

WHERE
{
  ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode.

  ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
          lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
          lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
          lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.

  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}
  
  FILTER (?date = "2019-08-01"^^xsd:date)
}

ORDER BY ?amount
```

Comment: you're getting a timeout for the second query compared to the first query because it's way more easy to evaluate a triple pattern with the object bound to a specific value by inline data (`VALUES`) which allows for using an index. Doing a filter on the values might use an index but the index for each datatype would have to exists - so the second query is just more complex and the shared medium has some timeout for public usage it looks like

Comment: honestly, their backend is rather slow it looks like. I tried even the simplified query here which takes ages: `SELECT ?transx {
        ?transx  lrppi:transactionDate ?date 
  FILTER (?date = "2019-08-01"^^xsd:date)
          }` - given that perfomance you should try to get the data locally if possible and use a more powerful triple store

Comment: Thanks, @UninformedUser. I've adapted the original query to include a long string of specific dates rather than a range- along the lines of:
```
WHERE
{
  VALUES (?date) {
  ("2021-07-01"^^xsd:date)
  ("2021-07-02"^^xsd:date)
  ("2021-07-03"^^xsd:date)
...}
Which takes advantage of the indexing you referenced. It's not elegant, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

I did a subselect with just the the triple pattern for the date and the filter in it.

The query returns now something but it's slow.

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category

WHERE
{
    {
      SELECT ?transx ?date WHERE {
        ?transx lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
        FILTER (?date = "2019-08-01"^^xsd:date)
      }
    
    }
  ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
          lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
          lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.

  
   ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode.


  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}
  
}

ORDER BY ?amount
```

OR

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category

WHERE
{
    {
        ?transx lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
        FILTER (?date = "2019-08-01"^^xsd:date)
    }
    ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
            lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
            lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.

  
    ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode.


    OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}
    OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}
    OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}
    OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
    OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}
  
}

ORDER BY ?amount
```

OR

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category

WHERE
{
    {
      
        ?transx lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
        FILTER (?date = "2019-08-01"^^xsd:date)
      
    
    }
    ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
            lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
            lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.

  
    ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode.


    OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}
    OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}
    OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}
    OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
    OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}
  
}

ORDER BY ?amount
```